# Trying to install splash in R, without luck

Tags: r, numpy, docker, scrapy-splash

---

EDIT: I followed Alistaire's advice below, and installed docker and numpy with pip.

However, this yields a new error, when running install_splash() in R:

```
     > install_splash()
       Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
         AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'errno' 

       3. stop(structure(list(message = "AttributeError: module 'os' has no 
          attribute 'errno'", 
              call = py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords), 
              cppstack = structure(list(file = "", line = -1L, stack = "C++ stack not available on this system"), class = 
            "Rcpp_stack_trace")), class = c("Rcpp::exception", 
          "C++Error", "error", "condition"))) 
       2.client$api$pull("scrapinghub/splash", tag) 
       1.install_splash()
```

When I rerun install_splash() with debug, I get the following message:

```
Detailed traceback: 
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\docker\api\image.py", line 380, in pull
    header = auth.get_config_header(self, registry)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\docker\auth.py", line 48, in get_config_header
    client._auth_configs, registry, credstore_env=client.credstore_env
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\docker\auth.py", line 96, in resolve_authconfig
    authconfig, registry, store_name, env=credstore_env
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\docker\auth.py", line 129, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
    data = store.get(registry)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\dockerpycreds\store.py", line 35, in get
    data = self._execute('get', server)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\dockerpycreds\store.py", line 89, in _execute
    if e.errno == os.errno.ENOENT:
```

What gives? I know Splash is up and running, and I've confirmed the correct installation of the docker and numpy modules with `pip freeze`.

---

**Original post:**

I am trying scrape tables off of a number of websites in R. To do this, I've been recommended to use Splash through Docker. I've downloaded Docker, and managed to get it up and running. Additionally, I've installed Python 3.5. I have pulled the Splash image through the command:

```
docker pull scrapinghub/splash
```

and started the container by the command:

```
docker run -p 8050:8050 -p 5023:5023 scrapinghub/splash
```

I've checked to see if Splash is indeed running properly, by checking 'http://localhost:8050/' on my browser - it works.

In R, I've run the following command:

```
> splash_active()
```

Which is returns this:

```
Status of splash instance on [http://localhost:8050]: ok. Max RSS: 73 Mb

[1] TRUE
```

So far so good. Now, I am trying to install Splash in R, by the command:

```
install_splash()
```

But R returns an error, saying:

```
Error: Python module docker was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\\python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/Lucas/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python37.dll
pythonhome:     C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
version:        3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:           [NOT FOUND]
docker:         [NOT FOUND]
```

What could be the issue? Is it related to 'numpy' and 'docker' not being found?

Comment: It's telling you you're missing some python modules (docker and numpy). Assuming you're not using conda, install them with pip at the command line: `pip install docker`

Comment: Aye. It unfortunately has a pretty hard requirement vis a vis the reticulated docker package. I'm waiting for https://github.com/richfitz/stevedore to get on CRAN so I can swap it out. However, you've got Splash running so you should just be able to use the `render_` functions (or the DSL) without worrying about `install_splash()`

Comment: Thanks gents. I've edited my original post, if you are interested in helping me further.